# StackOverflow in GUI class

Tags: java, user-interface, exception, reference, event-handling

Can someone please explain why I am receiving error messages...

I have two classes, one in which a GUI is created and the second class to handle events. The source code is shown below...

CLASS 1

```
        import javax.swing.*;
        import java.awt.*;

public class Motion extends JFrame {

MotionEvent controller = new MotionEvent();

//row 0
JPanel row0 = new JPanel();

//row 1
JPanel row1 = new JPanel();
JButton up = new JButton("Up");

//row 2
JPanel row2 = new JPanel();
JButton left = new JButton("Left");
JButton right = new JButton("Right");
JCheckBox compassFormat = new JCheckBox("compassFormat", false);

//row 3
JPanel row3 = new JPanel();
JButton down = new JButton("down");

Motion(){
    super("Motion Detector");
    setSize(500,325);
    setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    GridLayout layoutMaster = new GridLayout(5,1,10,10);
    setLayout(layoutMaster);

    add(row0);

    FlowLayout layout1 = new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.CENTER);
    row1.setLayout(layout1);
    up.addActionListener(controller);
    row1.add(up);
    add(row1);

    GridLayout layout2 = new GridLayout(1, 3, 10, 10);
    row2.setLayout(layout2);
    left.addActionListener(controller);
    //compassFormat.addItemListener(controller);
    right.addActionListener(controller);
    row2.add(left);
    row2.add(compassFormat);
    row2.add(right);
    add(row2);

    FlowLayout layout3 = new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.CENTER);
    row3.setLayout(layout3);
    row3.add(down);
    add(row3);

    setVisible(true);

}

public static void main(String[] args){
    Motion createGui = new Motion();
    }
}
```

CLASS 2

```
  import java.awt.event.*;
  import javax.swing.*;
public class MotionEvent implements ActionListener/*, ItemListener */{

Motion motionObj = new Motion();

public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event){
    Object objSource = event.getSource();
    if(objSource == motionObj.up){
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "You have moved up");
    }
    else if(objSource == motionObj.down){
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "You have moved down");
    }
    else if(objSource == motionObj.left){
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "You have moved left");
    }
    else if(objSource == motionObj.right){
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "You have moved right", "Navigator", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
    }
}

//public void itemStateChanged(ItemEvent event){


}//
```

The error messages received are:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.StackOverflowError
at sun.awt.Win32GraphicsConfig.getBounds(Native Method)
at sun.awt.Win32GraphicsConfig.getBounds(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Window.init(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Window.<init>(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Frame.<init>(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.JFrame.<init>(Unknown Source)
at Motion.<init>(Motion.java:26)
at MotionEvent.<init>(MotionEvent.java:5)
at Motion.<init>(Motion.java:6)
```

Motion.java:6 & MotionEvent.java:5 refer to the instantiation of the reference variables, is their anything wrong with them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an infinite loop running.Means `Motion` is created infinitely

Whenever an Object for `Motion` is created an Object for `MotionEvent` is also created

```
public class Motion extends JFrame {

 MotionEvent controller = new MotionEvent();
```

and whenever an Object for `MotionEvent` is created an Object for `Motion` is created

```
  public class MotionEvent implements ActionListener/*, ItemListener */{

  Motion motionObj = new Motion();//which will initiate endless call for this.Remove this
```

which in turn leads to an endless creation of those two objects which obviously results in stackoverflow error.
Remove

Comment: So do you suggest I remove one of the reference variables, either controller or motionObj?

Comment: You have to remove it in MotionEvent no need for other

Comment: Please [accept the answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work/5235#5235) if it helped solve the problem.I guess pretty much this is the cause of the probem

Comment: I mustn't remove it from the MotionEvent class, I must just create the reference variable inside the ActionPerformed method. 

That works fine, I will approve your answer.

Comment: For some reason when I click a button my GUI, it just opens a pop-up of the exact same GUI. I don't think my event handling code works properly. It was intended such that when a Button is pressed, a message box appears stating which direction was clicked on and hence the user moves in the specified direction. For some reason, when a (J)Button is clicked a new pop-up of the GUI appears

Comment: The source code for the Motion class is the same as above.
The source code for the MotionEvent class is exactly the same as what Fevly Pallar has shown below.

Comment: Replace `Object objSource = event.getActionCommand();` with `Object objSource = ((JButton)event.getSource()).getText();`

Answer (score 1):

That's a recursively call to `Motion` object use the following for your MotionEvent class

```
import java.awt.event.*;
  import javax.swing.*;
public class MotionEvent implements ActionListener/*, ItemListener */{
 public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event){
    Object objSource = event.getActionCommand();
    if(objSource.equals("Up")){
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "You have moved up");
    }
    else if(objSource .equals("Down")){
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "You have moved down");
    }
    else if(objSource.equals("Left")){
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "You have moved left");
    }
    else if(objSource.equals("Right")){
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "You have moved right", "Navigator", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
    }
}

//public void itemStateChanged(ItemEvent event){


}//
```

Comment: Yeah, I did that it works.

For some reason when I click a button my GUI, it just opens a pop-up of the exact same GUI. I don't think my event handling code works properly. 

It was intended such that when a Button is pressed, a message box appears stating which direction was clicked on and hence the user moves in the specified direction. For some reason, when a (J)Button is clicked a new pop-up of the GUI appears.